# How to set and get the new value of a decimal cell in the datagrid?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am tring to get the new value that a user set in a cell of a datagrid. The datagrid binds to a collection of the view model.

The type of the property that is binded in the cell is a decimal, that I would like to can set decimal values.

To get the value the new value, I use this code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Cantidad" Binding="{Binding Cantidad, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="false"/>

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CeldaFinalizandoEdicionCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

View model:

```
private RelayCommand _celdaFinalizandoEdicionCommand;
public RelayCommand CeldaFinalizandoEdicionCommand
{
    get { return _celdaFinalizandoEdicionCommand ?? (_celdaFinalizandoEdicionCommand = new RelayCommand(async param => await OnCeldaFinalizandoEdicion(), param => true)); }
}

private async Task OnCeldaFinalizandoEdicion()
{
    try
    {
        decimal myNewValue = SelectedItem.Cantidad;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The idea it is to handle the event CellEditEnding, so I could handle the cell edited. I need to set the binding mode of the cell to PropertyChanged, because if not, in the view model method I still get the old value.

I need to set the binding to two way, because if not, I would get a blank cell after editing.

However, this has a problem. To can write a decimal, I have to write the number without decimal point and then go to dot position and write it. If I write the dot decimal when there is not another number after it, it considerates it is a int value, because of validation. So it is hard to write a decimal value.

How could I could I write a decimal in a easy way when the binding property is a decimal?

Thanks.

Comment: You could hook into TextChanged event and bind to an IValueConverter instance, which you can design for your needs. That way, you're modifying your values before any validation starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has always worked for me. I hope I'm understanding your question right. Use the StringFormat in your Binding on the Column

Binding="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=N2}"